# Using fresco and MediaPlayer at the same time

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am using Fresco library to play a webp animation and I want to play a sound at the same time using android MediaPlayer, but the sound does not play, I tried playing sound in new Thread nut it did not work:

```
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
                        .scheme(UriUtil.LOCAL_RESOURCE_SCHEME)
                        .path(String.valueOf(R.drawable.onestaranimation))
                        .build();


                DraweeController controller =
                Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                        .setUri(uri)
                        .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
                        .build();
                missionEndAnimationOneStar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                missionEndAnimationOneStar.setController(controller);
                playSound(R.raw.onestarsound);


    private void playSound(int sound){

            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sound);
            mp.start();
        }
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

i tried using soundpool but it did not help so i create a service that it do everything for playing music like playing pausing resuming etc...

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the [AnimatedWebPDrawable](https://github.com/contriteobserver/AnimatedWebPDrawable) to present the animation, it seems compatible with MediaPlayer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please improve your answer by providing context for the link you shared. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for why this is important.